# Property exists but property_exists() return false;

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, laravel-5.4

Well I'm really confused. 
When i check if a property exists it returns false.

```
if (property_exists($pais, 'id'))
// false
```

but when I debug it shows me it's there.

```
print_r($pais->id);
// 1
print_r(property_exists($pais, 'id'));
// false
```

Am I crazy or my neurons just fried?

and the creation of pais is done by

```
if (key_exists('country', $data))
    $pais = Pais::adicionarPais($data);

(...) 

public static function adicionarPais(array $data)
{
    return Pais::firstOrCreate(['nome' => $data['country']]);
}
```

Comment: What is the context of `$pais`? Is it a standard object or a static object?

Comment: @RobertDeBoer iv updated with more info.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I see you're using Laravel, so I guess this are Eloquent models. They're probably using magic methods to create dynamic properties and methods from your database columns. Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

So, instead of having real properties, every time you request a property, they will check if there's any column or relationship and return that instead.

You can get your model attributes with the `getAttributes()` method (https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L851)

```
class Pais
{
    public function __get($name) {
        if ($name == 'id') {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
$pais = new Pais();
var_dump($pais->id); // int(1)
var_dump(property_exists($pais, 'id')); // bool(false)
```

Comment: Is this is the case, according to the PHP document, then this won't work. property_exists does not work on properties created by magic functions.

Comment: Exactly. That's why $pais->id returns 1 and property_exists return false.

Comment: Yes I'm using laravel.. but if i override its __get the eloquent will stop working and mess up all the relations..

Comment: thanx... seems like a good option. 
but its kind weird. i used this code in other contexts...  and worked fine....

Comment: Because ORM models are weird :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can convert the model to an array and then use `array_key_exists`. Eloquent object properties are set via magic methods, so `property_exists` will not work, especially if the property actually does exist but is set to `null`.

Example:

```
$pais = Pais::find(1);

if (array_key_exists('country', $pais->toArray())) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Note the use of `toArray` on the model.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Laravel and had the same issue.

The `$this->getAttributes()` in combination with `property_exists()` doesn't work, because `property_exists()` only works on objects and Classes, so you need `isset()` or `array_key_exists()`.

The problem with `isset()` is that if the key exists but the value is `null` it returns false, so it's not the same as `property_exists()`. The `array_key_exists()` does behave like `property_exists()` but is deprecated since PHP 7.4.

Solution: Cast the Array as an Object, and use `property_exists()`:

`property_exists((object)$this->getAttributes(), $key)`

Answer (score 0):

No need to go through it all and then if you are diligent and want to check what `getAttributes` or `toArray` Laravel functions return and what happens, we can use a combination of `isset` and `is_null` PHP core functions. I am concentrating here on Laravel and corresponding relationsip which is a bit of a more complex example but all the other variants can be extracted from below code. Enjoy and I hope it will save time. 
Let me try to elaborate with full proof Laravel example and Artisan Tinker.

Please bear with me.

Thank you **PHP Artisan Tinker!**

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|HasMany|object|null
 */
public function profile(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(User_profile::class, 'user_id', 'user_id')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

```
php artisan tinker

>>> $u = (new App\Models\User())->find(11549)
=> App\Models\User {#3481
     user_id: 11549,
     created_at: "2019-10-31 09:26:14",
     updated_at: "2019-10-31 09:26:14",
     first_name: "Pippy",
     middle_name: null,
     last_name: "Longstocking",
     phone: null,
     email: "11544@example.com",
     pincode: null,
     flag_is_active: 0,
     flag_is_email_subscribed: 1,
     flag_is_mobile_subscribed: 1,
     flag_terms_agreed: 1,
     flag_is_blocked: 0,
     flag_delete: 0,
     where_from: 1,
     employee_status: 0,
     remember_token: null,
     user_reference: "11544",
     alternate_user_reference: "11544",
     user_transaction_reference: null,
     user_channel: null,
     campaign_id: 0,
     ip_address: "172.31.10.23",
   }

>>> $u->profile()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany {#3483}

>>> $userProfile=$u->profile()->first();
=> null

>>> $userProfile->flag_ifisa
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'flag_ifisa' of non-object in Psy Shell code on line 1

>>> $userProfile->toArray()
PHP Error:  Call to a member function toArray() on null in Psy Shell code on line 1

>>> $userProfile->getAttributes()
PHP Error:  Call to a member function getAttributes() on null in Psy Shell code on line 1

>>> is_null($userProfile)
=> true

>>> isset($userProfile->flag_ifisa)
=> false
```